# LV Status: Not available. How to make it available?

Tags: linux, iscsi, lvm

I connect an iSCSI target, create a Physical Volume and Volume Group on it.

Then I create an LV, and

```
mkfs.ext3 /dev/vg00/vm
```

and all that works great.

Then I disconnect the target

```
iscsiadm -m node -T iqn.2004-04.com.qnap:ts-509:iscsi.linux01.ba4731 -p 192.168.0.4 -u
```

login to another Linux server, and connect the target there

```
iscsiadm -m node -T iqn.2004-04.com.qnap:ts-509:iscsi.linux01.ba4731 -p 192.168.0.4 -l
```

and I get:

```
linux01:~ # lvdisplay 
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                /dev/vg00/vm
  VG Name                vg00
  LV UUID                NBNRGV-FkSR-ZNZ9-9AVk-chLQ-j5nc-RazeBw
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Status              NOT available
      LV Size                17.00 GB
  Current LE             4352
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     0
```

I can see that `/dev/vg00/vm` doesn't exist, as I would have expected.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You need to activate a volume group after you attached it.

To activate all the inactive volumes on the system you would use a command like `vgchange -a y`.

Answer (score 12):

When you connect the target to the new system, the lvm subsystem needs to be notified that a new physical volume is available. You may need to call `pvscan`, `vgscan` or `lvscan` manually. Or you may need to call `vgimport vg00` to tell the lvm subsystem to start using `vg00`, followed by `vgchange -ay vg00` to activate it. Possibly you should do the reverse, i.e., `vgchange -an vg00; vgexport vg00` before detaching the target.

(I don't know anything about iSCSI, so maybe these steps are not necessary or should have been performed automatically by the iSCSI tools.)